# How does Gmail native unsubscribe link work?

Tags: gmail, unsubscribe, list-unsubscribe

When using the 'unsubscribe' in Gmail, what happens behind the scenes?

I would like to identify any users who have clicked the native unsubscribe link vs the one in the email footer.

Haven't been able to find any breakdown on what the unsubscribe technically means.
This article doesn't go enough detail to understand what, how and where information from Gmail is passed.
[https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8151?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#:~:text=getting%20these%20emails.-,On%20your%20computer%2C%20go%20to%20Gmail.,click%20Unsubscribe%20or%20Change%20preferences](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8151?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#:%7E:text=getting%20these%20emails.-,On%20your%20computer%2C%20go%20to%20Gmail.,click%20Unsubscribe%20or%20Change%20preferences).